# Choosing API level for Android

Tags: android

I understand the dilema in choosing a proper API on my Android project (more func vs. device market share) but what are your suggestions for proper level on a simple map using Retrofit and Google Maps?

Answer (score 0):

These days with the support libraries and all, it is not necessarily about offering more functionality, but more about how far you want to go to offer devices with API 23 the same as devices with API 15 for example.

Is it worth the extra 20 hours of development, just to add support for API 14 so you can reach 2% more users? It is all up to your needs and and wishes, how much time you have and how much time you want to spend.

Some times you will have no choice because your boss or his client makes the decision for you, but if the choice is yours alone, it all boils down you want **you** want and what is best in **your** situation.

<sub>Numbers used here are made up to illustrate the example.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I need an app than utilises Retrofit library to get marker info from web service and present it on a google map. What would be your suggestion for proper API?

Comment: @Jure I usually minSdk api 18, because I think users that stay behind and keep using older apis should just update their phones already. But it's up to you

Comment: Thanks Tim for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this definitely depends on your requirements. Do you already know the Android Dashboard?

https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

We recommend our customers API level 16, which targets > 90% of all devices currently. On the other hand, if its really just a simple app, why not support API level 9 as well, if it does not produce much more effort. A lot of new APIs are also backported via the Support-Libraries.

Maybe another question is, do you want to use some APIs which are only available for a specific API level? e.g. If you would like to target a arabic audience, it might be a good idea to start with API-Level 17, as it supports RTL-Layouts natively.